# Auto-fill program registration form

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, autofill

We use a program called vspace created by ncomputing. This allows for example 4 stations on a single host machine. So, each time this is installed we have to fill out the registration form which pops up when finalizing the installation. It only takes roughly 20 seconds or so to fill out, but that's 20 seconds for a couple hundred computers, so I am trying to find something that will take the information and fill it in.

I have no idea how to accomplish this. One thing it could do, is when I fill it out manually, I "tab" to the next block. If it could say, fill, tab, fill, tab and so forth with the pre-programmed data starting at whatever the currently selected field was, I think that might be easiest.

Here's a [photo of the registration screen](http://i122.photobucket.com/albums/o245/satanicpoohbear/Public%20View/IMG_20140630_104258231_HDR_zps2qdtz8q2.jpg). It defaults the cursor to the first block "name" and none of the drop boxes have to be edited.

Comment: I would start with [send keys](http://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html). Depending on your level of automation, you may try AppActivate or add a delay to the script and manually activate the window. You might also look into [silent installations](http://kb.ncomputing.com/kb/Installing-vSpace-from-the-Windows-Command-Line_303.html).

Comment: I'd recommend against using `SendKeys`, since it's flaky at best. Try something like [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/). Either way, your question is way too broad for SO.

Comment: So I looked into "AutoIt" and also looked into "Send Keys" and for what I am trying to accomplish "Send Keys" seems to be my best bet. Thats actually the type of answer I was looking for, but just did not know how to properly word it. As my scripting and coding experience is rather limited. The send keys as I use it seems to fail on occasion but it works the majority of the time, as long as I put a sleep timer on it and select the first box in the form. Thanks for the help.

Comment: now i am very new to actual posting here.... so do i now need to say which answer worked best for me, or some way mark the question as answered?

Comment: The above are just comments, not actual answers, so there's nothing to accept for you. And on a more general note, this particular type of question is more suitable for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) than for StackOverflow.